# Empty CSV file when exporting from Google big query

Tags: google-bigquery, export-to-csv

When I try to export data for GBQ -

the first line works -

`bq query --max_rows=10000 --format=csv > out.csv`

This not:

`bq query --max_rows=10000000 --format=csv > out.csv`

We got:

> Waiting on bqjob_r40***** ... (0s) Current status: DONE

But `out.csv` is empty

Comment: do you have a job id?

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I am having the same problem when exporting big file too.